# Is it possible for a Turing machine to be able to reduce a grammar and tell where it fits in chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: turing-machines, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

For example:
This looks like a context free grammar:
 → 
 →  | 
 →  | 
 →  | c

but it can be reduced to this regular language:
 →  | 
 →  | 
 →  | c

I want to know if it is possible or not and why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible: it is undecidable whether a context-free grammar describes a regular language. For a proof, see e.g. [*Undecidable Problems for Context-free Grammars*](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~hoogeboomhj/second/codingcomputations.pdf) by Hendrik-Jan Hoogeboom.

Comment: And for knowing what kind of grammar it is without reducing, is it possible to use a turing machine to find that out?

Comment: Yes. You only need to verify some constraints on the shape of its rules. We can do that, and so can a Turing machine.