# Is there a way a proving a language regular/non-regular that works for every possible language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

In my theory of computing class, we've been talking about how to prove languages regular and non-regular. I've heard of methods like the pumping lemma and Kolmogorov complexity to prove languages non-regular, while proving languages regular revolves around building a DFA, or using the Myhill-Nerode theorem. All of these approaches fail for some language. Is there some approach that will work for all regular/non-regular languages?

Comment: It looks like you have an inkling of what is going to come in your computing class. There will be quite a few theorems and facts stating that there is no general approach for many problems. The key word is "decidability" or "[undecidability](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undecidability?sort=votes)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. It is undecidable, even for context-free languages. It is decidable for *deterministic* context-free languages.

References are easy to find with Google; for instance,

- [*Undecidable Problems for Context-free Grammars*](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~hoogeboomhj/second/codingcomputations.pdf), by Hendrik Jan Hoogeboom
- [*Deciding whether a context-free language is regular [closed]*](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30771/deciding-whether-a-context-free-language-is-regular), on the *Theoretical Computer Science* Stack Exchange, in which user *babou* lists

  - [A regularity test for pushdown machines](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995867905918),  R.E. Stearns, Information and Control, 1967 (full text by clicking on the page)
  - [Regularity and Related Problems for Deterministic Pushdown Automata](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.8903&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Leslie G. Valiant, JACM 1975

Comment: Is it a failure of this site that you have been participating for 6 years no reference from this site is chosen?

Comment: Not at all, but i didn't want to refer to myself.

Comment: @Apass.Jack In fact, if you like recursion, the first link "Undecidable problems .." has an acknowledgement: "*Parts of this overview were inspired by answers on stackexchange, like for instance by users reinierpost and Sylvain.*"

Comment: If you have written good answers explaining these things, please link to them. There is nothing wrong with self-citation, as long as the cited material is relevant. It's just not helpful to deliberately write an answer that is less good than you could easily make it.

Comment: All I've done is referred to Hendrik Jan's overview in [another answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93831/is-it-possible-for-a-turing-machine-to-be-able-to-reduce-a-grammar-and-tell-wher/93832#93832) but to a different question. I've searched harder, and I can't find a duplicate of the exact question above on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Myhill–Nerode works for every language: every regular language has a finite number of equivalence classes, and every non-regular language has an infinite number.

However, there is no general method for actually using Myhill–Nerode. Like all mathematical proofs, creativity is needed to find the equivalence classes. As [reinierpost says](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/104932/9550), there is no algorithm you can use to determine whether a context-free grammar produces a regular language (i.e., one with a finite number of Myhill–Nerode classes).